# SQLite database fetch all data to Recyclerview via adapter.(looking for preferences)

Tags: android, json, sqlite, parsing

I am working with SQLite database and Recyclerview with adapter.
my problem is, how can i convert/parse my data in SQLite database into JSON (i like to store all my data to my constructor and fetch via adapter followed my displaying the adapter with Recyclerview).

ps. please ask me for other details, thanks a lot :)

anyway, this is my codes:

my codes:

```
               //sqliteselectReader
               DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new 
               DatabaseHelper(getContext());
                SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                Cursor c=databaseHelper.selectDisplaySchedule(db);


 my recyclerview binds with adapter:

              List<ScheduleDisplayDetails> get ="**my problem is here**"//I would like to fetch my data from database here on my getter setter. 


                        layoutManager = new 
              LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
                        RecyclerView recyclerView = inflatedView.
                        findViewById(R.id.scheduleRecycler);
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new 
              DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), 
              LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
                        ScheduleModuleAdapter recyclerViewAdapter =
                        new ScheduleModuleAdapter(get);

                        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
```

My DBQuery:

```
    public Cursor selectDisplaySchedule(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "SELECT ScheduleId, ScheduleLocation, ScheduleLatitude, 
    ScheduleLongitude, ScheduleExpectedTimeOfTransaction, 
    ScheduleEstimatedTimeOfDeparture, ScheduleStatus from tFleetSchedule;";
    return (db.rawQuery(sql, null));
}
```

these is my data I would like to store (I've open via sqlite browser,sorry other data is confidential):
[image]

This is my GetterSetter:

```
public class ScheduleDisplayDetails {

private String ID;
private String Location;
private String Latitude;
private String Longitude;
private String ExpectedTimeOfTransaction;
private String EstimatedTimeOfDeparture;
private String Status;

public ScheduleDisplayDetails(String ID, String location, String latitude, String longitude, String expectedTimeOfTransaction, String estimatedTimeOfDeparture, String status) {
    this.ID = ID;
    Location = location;
    Latitude = latitude;
    Longitude = longitude;
    ExpectedTimeOfTransaction = expectedTimeOfTransaction;
    EstimatedTimeOfDeparture = estimatedTimeOfDeparture;
    Status = status;
}

public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(String ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return Location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    Location = location;
}

public String getLatitude() {
    return Latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    Latitude = latitude;
}

public String getLongitude() {
    return Longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    Longitude = longitude;
}

public String getExpectedTimeOfTransaction() {
    return ExpectedTimeOfTransaction;
}

public void setExpectedTimeOfTransaction(String expectedTimeOfTransaction) {
    ExpectedTimeOfTransaction = expectedTimeOfTransaction;
}

public String getEstimatedTimeOfDeparture() {
    return EstimatedTimeOfDeparture;
}

public void setEstimatedTimeOfDeparture(String estimatedTimeOfDeparture) {
    EstimatedTimeOfDeparture = estimatedTimeOfDeparture;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return Status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    Status = status;
}
```

}

this is my adapter:

```
   public class ScheduleModuleAdapter extends 
   RecyclerView.Adapter<ScheduleModuleAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<ScheduleDisplayDetails> schedlist;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView location, schedule_status, id, expected, estimated;


    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        location = view.findViewById(R.id.schedule_location);
        estimated = view.findViewById(R.id.schedule_estimated_time);
        schedule_status = view.findViewById(R.id.schedule_Status);
        expected = view.findViewById(R.id.schedule_expected_time);
        id = view.findViewById(R.id.schedule_ID);


    }
}


public ScheduleModuleAdapter(List<ScheduleDisplayDetails> scheduleList) {
    this.schedlist = scheduleList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.schedule_module_card_view, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ScheduleDisplayDetails sched = schedlist.get(position);
    holder.location.setText(sched.getLocation());
    holder.schedule_status.setText(sched.getStatus());
    holder.estimated.setText(sched.getEstimatedTimeOfDeparture());
    holder.expected.setText(sched.getExpectedTimeOfTransaction());
    holder.id.setText(sched.getID());

     }


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return schedlist.size();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop tru the `Cursor`, create each object per iteration and set the values:

```
//sqliteselectReader
               DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new 
               DatabaseHelper(getContext());
                SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                Cursor c=databaseHelper.selectDisplaySchedule(db);

ArrayList<ScheduleDisplayDetails> get = new ArrayList<>(); initialize your list

while(c.moveToNext()) {
    ScheduleDisplayDetails details = new ScheduleDisplayDetails(); // you should create an empty constructor also on your object

    details.setID(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ScheduleId")));
    details.setLocation(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ScheduleLocation")));
    //set other details also....

    get.add(details); // add the object on your list
}

//then setup your recyclerview and adapter...
```

Comment: thanks men, I am newbie in development.. also trying this to fix this one but i don't know the logic. by the way, thanks a lot :D this is the best answer for this one.

Comment: happy to help :)